For loop not reaching the else if statement when using the expression found=$?
i'm attempting to write a github actions script that checks for a particular text pattern in only prod files only and produces an error message if the results match the regex. However for some reason if the matching fails i expected the script to pass based on the "else" statement i have? The current behaviour is if the regex matching fails the script still fails and does not display the expected message "All is good".
set -euo pipefail
FILE_PATTERNS="myfile/[A-Za-z]+/(tr1|gf6|ty6|ppl)/.*"
regex="ref=master"
result=0
for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
    if [[ ("${file}" =~ $FILE_PATTERNS) ]]; then
       continue
    else
       grep -q "${regex}" "${file}";
       found=$?
       echo $?
       if [ $found -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Error: Test123"
        else
            echo "All is good"
       fi
    fi
done
exit $result


Why would you write that code in the first place? if grep -q "$regex" "$file"; then echo "Error: Test123"; else echo "All is good"; fi -- no need for any $? or found variable at all.

Anyhow, the immediate problem is set -euo pipefail causing the script to immediately exit if grep has a nonzero status. set -e is evil; don't ever use it. (Yes, without set -e you need to write a lot of code that explicitly checks exit statuses -- foo || exit, foo || return, etc; but that's better than subtle version-dependent bugs).

As a separate issue, you need to be concerned about malicious filenames -- what if all_changed_files contains a file named myfile/$(rm -rf ~)/got_you_good, for example?; generally speaking, using templates to substitute data into code is inherently insecure, and any CI system designed by people who thought it was okay shouldn't be used by anyone.

(mind, the rm case might not matter in a CI system, but a command that exfiltrates secret keys or pulls down and executes arbitrary code to infect the builds you're creating would matter much more; treat it as an example, not a worst-case)

(to back up the "version-dependent" claim -- see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ for a chart showing how set -e behavior differs across shells, and also the exercises section of the BashFAQ #105 page linked above)

@CharlesDuffy thank you for your comments, i have now managed to resolve this
